# How to define the $r$th harmonic number if $r$ is any real number?

Tags: harmonic-numbers

What would be the value of

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}\frac{1}{k}$$

Is it $H_{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}$?

Using different definitions of harmonic numbers this question can be computed, but can I use the usual definition of harmonic numbers for any real numbers?

In other words is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$

A useful definition for any real $n$?

When I want to compute the value of $H_{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}}$ at [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) I just define $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ and I don't put $\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$ directly at the upper limit, but I define $n=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$ and the result is exactly what it should be, it seems using a simple substitution will give us the right answer, but generally are we allowed to use the regular definition of harmonic numbers when our $n$ is not necessarily a natural number?

Comment: I would define the $r$th harmonic number for a real number $r$ which is not a negative integer for example by $H_r = \gamma +\psi(r+1)$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers)

Comment: Things are even more complicated. Suppose you have a function of $f(n)$ in the domain of real $n$ for which $f(n) = H_n$ for positive integers $n$. Then $g(n) = f(n) + a \sin(\pi n)$ is another extension of  $H_n$ to real $n$. Hence you need an additional condition to rule out $a\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Indefinite Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum)  concept is the answer to your question.

In fact,  if a function $f(x)$ is the (forward) difference of a function $F(x)$
$$
f(x) = \Delta _x F(x) = F(x + 1) - F(x)
$$
then we say that $F(x)$ is the "antidifference" (or "indefinite sum") of $f(x)$
$$
F(x) = \Delta _x ^{\left( { - 1} \right)} f(x) = \sum\nolimits_x {f(x)} 
$$

If $ f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are defined over a real, or complex, domain for $x$ then we will have for example
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {f(x + k)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( {F(x + 1) - F(x)} \right)}  = F(x + n + 1) - F(x)
$$

We write the above  with a different symbol for the sum as
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\,n} {f(x + k)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {f(x + k)}  = F(x + n) - F(x)
$$
which can also be written as
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k = x}^{\,x + n} {f(k)}  = F(x + n) - F(x)
$$

The extension to 
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k = a}^{\,b} {f(k)}  = F(b) - F(a)
$$
for any real (or complex) $a,b$ inside the domain of definition of $f, F$ is quite natural.

Coming to the harmonic numbers,  it is well known that the functional equation of the digamma function is
$$
{1 \over x} = \Delta _x \,\psi (x)
$$
and it is therefore "natural" to define
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
H_r  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^r {{1 \over k}}  = \sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{\,1 + r} {{1 \over k}}  = \psi (1 + r) - \psi (1) = \psi (1 + r) + \gamma 
 } \tag{1}$$
which substantiate *M. Janisch's* comment

Answering to *W. Hintze*'s comment, please consider how the "indefinite sum" parallels the "indefinite integral - antiderivative" concept.
Similarly to
$$
f(x) = {d \over {dx}}F(x)\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad F(x) = \int {f(x)dx}  + c
$$
we have that
$$
f(x) = \Delta \,F(x)\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad F(x) = \sum\nolimits_x {f(x)}  + \pi \left( x \right)
$$
where now the family of  antidifference functions differ by any function $\pi(x)$ , and not by a constant, which is periodic
with  period (or one of the periods) equal to $1$, as you rightly noticed.

So by "natural extension" I meant to say:
 - an extension from integers to reals (and complex) field under the "indefinite sum" concept,
which provides a function $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ which fully interpolates $f(n)$;
 - in the antidifference family to select the "simpliest / smoothiest" function, same as 
the Gamma function is selected among the functions satisfying $F(z+1)=zF(z)$ as the
only one which is [logarithmically convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem),
or which has the simplest Weierstrass representation, etc.

From the comments I could catch some skepticism as if my answer could just be an "extravagant" personal
idea of mine.
 That's absolutely not so, the definition in (1) is actually **standardly accepted**: refer to 
[Wolfram Function Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber/02/), 
and in particular [to this section](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/introductions/DifferentiatedGammas/02/) or to the
[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Harmonic_numbers_for_real_and_complex_values).
I am just trying to enlight how we can assign a meaning to sums with bounds which are not integral and thus saying that 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
H_{\,1 + \sqrt {5/2} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\,1 + \sqrt {5/2} } {{1 \over k}}  = \sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{\,\,2 + \sqrt {5/2} } {{1 \over k}}  = \psi (\,\,2 + \sqrt {5/2} ) - \psi (1) = 1.7068 \ldots 
 } \tag{2}$$

Comment: I don't believe that the indefinite sum provides an answer to the question. If you believe it does, you should explain that in your answer. Just giving a link is not an adequate response.

Comment: @RobArthan:  your criticism is fully right and accepted: I expanded my answer

Comment: So finally can I use an irrational index for the lower or upper bound for the sum?

Comment: @ G Cab As to the question of what is a "natural" extension please see my comment to the OP. (and thanks for bringing indefinite sums to my attention).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze:  well, the meaning of "natural extension" is .. quite *natural*, as much as the Gamma function is the natural extension of $(n-1)!$. That the "natural" one does not cover all the possible extensions that's absolutely true: I added some lines to make it clear which is the antidifference family of functions.

Comment: @GCab, thanks for the answer, I used this notion for  [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541910/limit-of-a-n-frac113-cdot-1-frac113-cdot-223-cdot-1-cdots-fra/3542440#3542440) and I was  wondering  if it's possible to define harmonic numbers such that

Comment: @user715522: I don't know I could better explain that there is a natural and **standardly recognized** extension to real and complex indices of Harmonic N. since nobody upvotes the answer above neither you yourself is accepting it ! So, your use of them in the cited answer (which I already noticed and upvoted) is perfectly **lecit** (apart from being $H_{\,\sqrt {5/2} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\, \sqrt {5/2} } {{1 \over k}} 
$)

Comment: @GCab, I accept your nice answer and thank you for your effort (+1)

Comment: @  G Cab "From the comments I could catch some skepticism as if my answer could just be an "extravagant" personal idea of mine." No, this is not at all an "extravagant idea". My comment just wanted to point out an interesting additional topic in the field of extending the domain from integer to real/complex: what are the conditions to be observed in this extension to make it unique?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: glad that we cleared our understanding.  The extension cannot be unique, as told there is a full family of functions differing by any periodic function with one of the periods = 1. Which to select is a matter of mathematical "aestetics" / convenience. If you know about Gamma and what makes it "unique" that will reflect on $\psi$

Comment: @ G. Cab nice that you are telling me now what I pointed out to you.

Answer (score 1):

> The  $n$-th harmonic  number  $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ admits  a   nice representation  as  integral  of  a *[finite  geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*  which can  be  generalised  in a rather *natural* way. We have  the following  representation  for  $n$ a positive integer:
>   \begin{align*}
> H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}dt\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The  identity  (1) is valid since we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}dt&=\int_0^1\left(1+t+\cdots+t^{n-1}\right)\,dt\tag{2}\\
&=\left(t+\frac{1}{2}t^2+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}t^n\right)\bigg|_0^1\tag{3}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(0\right)\tag{4}\\
&=H_n
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply  the  finite geometric series formula.
- In (3) we  do  the integration.
- In (4) we   evaluate the   expression  at the upper and  lower  limit.

> The representation (1) indicates  a  *generalisation*
>   \begin{align*}
> H_\color{blue}{r}=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^\color{blue}{r}}{1-t}dt\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   for   real  values $r$ in fact also for complex values.

*Note:*

- The formula (2) can be found in the wiki page *[generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Harmonic_numbers_for_real_and_complex_values)*.
- We have an interesting relationship with the *[Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations)* $\psi(r)$ which has an integral representation
  \begin{align*}
  \psi(r+1)=\int_0^1\frac{1-t^r}{1-t}\,dt-\gamma
  \end{align*}
  which is strongly related to (2). Here  $\gamma$ is the *[Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)*.
- If we stick at the sigma notation, we often find for real upper limit $r$ the meaning
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^r a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor r\rfloor}a_k
  \end{align*}
  where $\lfloor .\rfloor$ is the *[floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)*.

Comment: You are rigt : in the "traditional" sum notation writing $\sum\limits_{k = r}^s {a_{\,k} } $
actually means $\sum\limits_{k = \,\left\lceil r \right\rceil }^{\left\lfloor s \right\rfloor } {a_{\,k} } $.
That's why we need to extend the meaning passing to the *antidifference* and using a slightly different symbol.

Comment: @GCab: I think the simpler approach via the integral representation already does the job to generalize $H_n$ appropriately.

Comment: Definitely yes, the integral representation does the job very nicely. But I understand the core of the post as being whether and what meaning to assign to a sum with non-integral bounds

Comment: @GCab: Yes, I know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is "are we allowed to use the regular definition of harmonic numbers when our $n$ is not necessarily a natural number?" The answer is **no**, since the "regular definition" of a **sum** is $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$. Here $n$ is the number of summands which can't be a non natural number.

But you can very well give a meaning to the **result of a sum**. And this result may accept non integers as input.

Take the simpler example of a "sum" $a(\pi) = \text{"}\sum_{k=1}^{\pi} k\text{"}$. This "sum" is not defined, as although the first three summands are 1, 2, and 3, the last 3.14...-th summand is not defined.

Hence the definition starts by calculating the sum up to an integer $n$, and **afterwards** insert the non integer value for $n$. Here this gives the arithmetic sum $a(n)= \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$, and hence $a(\pi)= \frac{1}{2}\pi(\pi+1)$.

Now for the harmonic number there is no such simple closed expression for general $n$. But here comes a relation which is valid for natural $n$:  $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 x^{k-1}\,dx=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^n x^{k-1}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx$, and now the r.h.s. is valid for also for real $n$.

Your description of the problem gives a good illustration of this procedure. In making the usual definition of the harmonic number $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ in your CAS, the system understands that you mean the harmonic number function $H_n$ it has in its "belly", and this is valid for real numbers. If you then insert a value for $n$, be it integer or not, you get the result of this internal function.

Comment: **please, let's avoid confusions**, do not use the symbol $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{\,\pi } k $ in your argumentation above
since it is the symbol adopted (almost standardly) for the antidifference,  and
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{\,\pi } k  = {{\pi \left( {\pi  - 1} \right)} \over 2}
$$ !
Use instead, 
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\pi  k  = \sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{\,\pi  + 1} k  = {{\pi \left( {\pi  + 1} \right)} \over 2}
$$
And please have a look at the renowned and authoritative "concrete Mathematics" para. 2.6

Comment: You might have noticed that I have put the expression in hyphens to avoid confusion. You are free to use any symbol you like, of course, but please avoid forcing others to use your conventions.